# Using Japanese layout, how to input accented letters?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

Behind the Japanese layout there seems to be a standard US layout, however only US-International is extended for the use of accented letters. Is there a way to utilise it? Or any other way to input accented letters with the Japanese layout (romaji mode)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some solutions of various utility:

- Learn the numeric codes for the characters you need and enter them using
  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>,
  using perhaps for ease of use a hotkey mapper such as
  [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
- Use the Windows `charmap` utility
- Perhaps the best solution: Use the free and open-source utility
  [wincompose](https://github.com/samhocevar/wincompose),
  which adds a software Compose key that allows combining characters, such as in
  <kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> giving
  <kbd>é</kbd>.

Comment: Last one is indeed the best solution. Went with that one. Appreciate the help